# Creating an Azure DevOps Pipeline using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to create an Azure DevOps Pipeline from a yaml file using Powershell and I'd like to know if there is another method to accomplish this other than Rest API which I have read that's an option and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-cli%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser#faq) of creating an Azure DevOps pipeline does not cover Powershell.